# IBM Cloud Functions: Is it possible to have a function made of multiple Javascript files?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

So I am trying to deploy a function that uses multiple javascript files. The only way I see to deploy a function is with a single index.js file. Is there some what to add more files?

I have the CLI setup but still only see examples uploading a single js file rather than a zip.

Comment: You mean a single function `Foo()` that is broken down on multiple separate js files? Why would you need that?

Comment: An IBM Cloud Function. The function they provide expects to be in index.js. I want the main() function to be able to call other functions in different files. Normally you would use require("file/path") to access other files but I don't see a way to upload other files. The program has been deployed on AWS Lambda and GCF and was split into multiple files to be more organized.

Comment: Ah I see, the initial wording of the post title and body combined makes things confusing. I would suggest an edit for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Having an IBM Cloud Functions action that has its logic contained in multiple files is supported, not just for Node.js / Javascript. The [documentation for IBM Cloud Function has a section on how to create an action as Node.js module](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-creating-javascript-actions#openwhisk_js_packaged_action). You would then pack the files as single ZIP file and upload it when you create or update the action.

Alternatives would be to [package all into a single file using webpack](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-creating-javascript-actions#openwhisk_js_webpack_action) or [using Docker actions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-creating-docker-actions#creating-docker-actions).